# Upgrading Ubuntu Server 22.10 Kinetic Kudu to 23.10 Mantic

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am trying to upgrade my ubuntu server 22.10 Kinetic Kudu to 23.10 mantic.

I was able to upgrade my Kinetic release up to the latest updates by using this sources.list:

```
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic universe
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates universe
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic multiverse
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security main restricted
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security universe
```

When i execute the do-release-upgrade, i get the following message:

> An upgrade from 'kinetic' to 'mantic' is not supported with this tool

Is it indeed impossible to perform the upgrade path i am trying to do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Finally i was able to do the upgrade with the following steps:

- Modify your current /etc/apt/sources.list and replace the urls starting with **http://archive**... by **http://old-releases**
- Once done, execute **sudo apt update** then **sudo apt upgrade** and **sudo apt dist-upgrade**
- Then reboot
- Modify the /etc/apt/sources.list and put back **archive** instead of **old-releases**
- Modify the /etc/apt/sources.list and replace all occurences of **kinetic** by **lunar**
- Then perform **sudo apt update**, **sudo apt upgrade** and **sudo apt dist-upgrade**. This will ensure that you upraded to 23.04
- Then reboot
- Then do a sudo do-release-upgrade to upgrade to 23.10

Comment: Great answer!!! It's the right response. I could be able to full upgrade my system.

Comment: It's insane that they can't just forward both "archive.ubuntu" and "old-releases.ubuntu" to the same update server... ridiculous way to break updates...

Answer (score 6):

I had the same "not supported" error upgrading from 22.10 (Kinetic Kudu) to 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur). I was able to trick `do-release-upgrade` into upgrading to 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) first:

1. Do your `apt update` and `apt upgrade` first and reboot
2. Edit `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` - this file tells `do-release-upgrade` where to find information about the latest releases
3. Comment out this existing `URI` line and point it to an older copy of the meta-release file from the Wayback Machine:

   ```
   #URI = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
   URI = https://web.archive.org/web/20230917010657id_/http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
   ```
4. Run `do-release-upgrade` - this will get your system to 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
5. Edit `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` again and restore the original `URI`
6. Run another `do-release-upgrade` - this will get your system to 23.10 (Mantic Minotaur)

A couple of notes on how this works:

- `do-release-upgrade` pretty much always tries to upgrade the system to the latest available release, and has very few documented ways to control its behaviour

  - `--devel-release` lets you upgrade to the unstable/preview version of the next release
  - Setting `Prompt=lts` in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` will only upgrade to LTS releases
- The file the URI points to is expected as a plain text file, while Wayback Machine usually serves them wrapped in HTML - adding `id_` at the end of the timestamp returns the raw file.

Answer (score 2):

The good news is, Linux is as easier to use now than Windows, so unlike an on a Windows machine, where you pull it out after 2 years and have to spend hours installing automatic updates, with Ubuntu,all you have to do is:

```
Modify your current /etc/apt/sources.list and replace the urls starting with http://archive... by http://old-releases
Once done, execute sudo apt update then sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt dist-upgrade
Then reboot
Modify the /etc/apt/sources.list and put back archive instead of old-releases
Modify the /etc/apt/sources.list and replace all occurences of kinetic by lunar
Then perform sudo apt update, sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt dist-upgrade.
```

Then wait a few hours for the upgrades to install.
This will ensure that you upraded to 23.04
Then reboot. Make sure to test the system to make sure everything is working properly.

Then do a sudo do-release-upgrade to upgrade to 23.10 and wait a few more hours for the new updates to install. This is why Linux is just hands down superior to Windows. Its so much easier.

Seriously though,I can't give this to my elderly mother and expect her to have a prayer of getting it to work. We are our own worst enemy.